# Is it possible to use React libraries in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

Recently I started working on React-Native, earlier I used to work on React, as I'm new to it I am struggling to work on many requirements for example the drag/drop among two lists which actually is pretty simple while using HTML/React but it's so complex in React-Native, there's no library to support the feature and i never of such struggle, is there a way I can use any React library in React-Native or can anyone help me with React-Native library where I can use Draggable Flatlists to drag among each other as well as having the option to move it to the other list.

I'm struggling with this requirement for last weeks and had googled a lot.

Tried some React-Native libraries as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react library actually does not have anything related to `Browser DOM HTML`. Anything related to it separated into `react-dom` package. `React Native` does not and cannot use this library, because you don't have DOM underneath a react native application. However you can use most of the code/functionality you wrote for your mobile app in the browser, if you install necessary transpiling library. This is possible because react native defines some primitive components that can be ported to almost any platform. If you still want to use just HTML to render inside react native, you may use `WebView` for it.

this is a great explanation by iamwebgeek user. hope it helps